# How to select just one id from a set of repetitive records in SQL and select only one of the corresponding values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table called students_classrooms which represents the relationship between students and classrooms.
I have been wondering if there is a way I could get for each classroom one randomly assign student only with SQL query.

Looking for result like this:
classroom  -  student (2,3)(3,77)

students are selected ranmdomly.

I have been trying different configurations solutions, but non of them seems to be working, would appreciate any suggestions, thanks!!

```
SELECT student_id, classroom_id
from students_classrooms
where classroom_id in (2,3)
```

[image: students_classrooms]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: no, what I need is to get one random student from the students assigned to each classroom. So xe from classroom 2 just one student chosen randomly, same for classroom 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
SELECT classroom_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(student_id ORDER BY RAND()),',',1) AS student
FROM students_classrooms 
WHERE classroom_id IN (2,3)
GROUP BY classroom_id;
```

Use `GROUP_CONCAT(student_id ORDER BY RAND())` then extract the first `student_id` appeared in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` list using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75393f34b835b05bbaf863cc62a6376e)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
select ( 
         select t2.student_id 
         from students_classrooms t2 
         where t2.classroom_id = t1.classroom_id 
     order by rand() limit 1 
    ) as student_id,
          t1.classroom_id
from students_classrooms t1
group by classroom_id
order by rand() ;
```

The subquery randomly searches the same table, referencing the classroom_id, generating a random list

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9338d7e46e036474f9f1ff1871298d1c)